# Updating GTK+ on Scientific Linux 6.2

Tags: linux, gtk, centos, rhel

I am building out an install of Scientific Linux 6.2 with gretl, and need to update GTK+ to at least version 2.4.0.  Are there any issues in doing so? If not, what are the recommended steps?

Answer (score 0):

You may download source from official website GTK+ and build rpm packet from source.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you aware of any issues when updating from version 2.2 to 2.4?

Comment: You shoud of course update all depend package. I know, but it is obvious if you want replace old package.